# Beginner Ord Print and Table Format Question

Tags: python, printing, format, ord

I have to write a code that produces the following:

```
Letter Code
  A     65
  B     66
  C     67
  D     68
  E     69

...

  Z     90
```

I have this written but it isn't working:

```
test_str = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
print("Letter " + " Code")
for chr in test_str:
  print(chr)
for ord in test_str:
  print(ord)
```

I can't get the ord Unicode to print and I don't know how to format so the letters and code end up in table format.

Any help for this beginner would be appreciated.

Comment: Please take a moment to format your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
test_str = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
print("Letter " + " Code")
for chr in test_str:
     print(chr,ord(chr))
```

Comment: Please, update your answer considering reading [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you!  I am still getting errors.  Here is what I get using your suggestion:Letter  Code
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-35940064accd> in <module>()
      2 print("Letter " + " Code")
      3 for chr in test_str:
----> 4      print(chr,ord(chr))

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: that's strange. Are you running the code within a Jupyter Notebook ? Are you running Python 3 ?